# Generics Array - Cannot be cast

Tags: java, generics

I run the method

```
MyObject[] myObjects = append(MyObject.class, myObjectCurrentArray, append1, append2, append3);

public static final <T> T [] append(Class T, T[] array, T... appendThese){
    T[] newArray = new Object[array.length + appendThese.length];
    //put T[] array and T...appendThese into newArray
    return newArray;
}
```

This throws the Exception

> java.lang.ClassCastException: [Ljava.lang.Object; cannot be cast to [Lxxx.MyObject;

How should I fix this?

Comment: I vote to reopen this question, as I don't believe the "duplicate question" addresses OP's issue, especially because OP is looking to concatenate to an already-existing array with elements of the same type.  I have an explicit solution to solve their problem.